# Update interrupted, now can't update Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, upgrade, updates, internet

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04. While I was updating it there was an internet interruption. Now I'm unable to update, upgrade and install any app/program through terminal/software center (by connecting internet). Is there any way that I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Open a terminal and post any error messages when you run `sudo apt-get -f`

Comment: @Naveen No, please try this instead. `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `sudo apt-get -f install`, it should fix the packages that may be corrupted.

After that, please perform a `sudo apt-get update`.